# Convolution of two mixture of densities in R

Tags: r, probability, convolution, probability-density

I am currently trying to do a convolution between a mixture of two lognormal densisites in R using package "distr". The mixtures are given by:

```
library(distr)
M1 <- UnivarMixingDistribution(Lnorm(meanlog=8.1,sdlog=0.02),
                               Lnorm(meanlog=8.15,sdlog=0.035),
                               mixCoeff = c(0.45,0.55))

M2 <- UnivarMixingDistribution(Lnorm(meanlog=8.17,sdlog=0.035),
                               Lnorm(meanlog=8.15,sdlog=0.03),
                               mixCoeff = c(0.65,0.35))
```

Both these functions should deliver positive probabilities in the area X=[3000,4000]. However when I do the convolution:

```
conv <- convpow(M1+M2,1)
M3  <- d(conv) 
M3(seq(3000,4000,by=1))
```

I get all zero probabilities and in fact the PDF is located around the 7000 area. Can someone please help me to do this convolution correctly?

Comment: I think you are doing it correctly! Convolution refers to finding distribution of the sum of two random variables. If you are just trying to multiply them that's something different.

Comment: My advice is to plot M1, M2, and the convolution of M1 and M2 to see if you're on the right track.